# How to fix radio button validation in jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, radio-button

I am using a jQuery plugin called [Stepy](http://www.wbotelhos.com/stepy/), which is based of the [FormToWizard](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx) plugin, to allow users to complete a 10-step form.  Stepy integrates with the jQuery Validation plugin.

I am running into an issue where if there are multiple radio buttons on the form, it throws and error and does not let the user continue.  This only happens after the first radio button (the first radio button validates fine) and only when there are steps after the radio button (if the radio button is on the last step it works fine).

FireBug is displaying "a is undefined".  Also, this only seems to happen when the Validation plugin is activated ("validate: true").

Looking through the Stepy and jQuery Validate code, I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

I have a working example posted: http://jsfiddle.net/5Rd7A/3/

Any ideas?

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

    $('#custom').stepy({
      backLabel: 'Backward',
      block: true,
      errorImage: true,
      nextLabel: 'Forward',
      titleClick: true,
      validate: true
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="custom" name="custom">
      <fieldset title="Thread 1">
        <legend>description one</legend>
        <label>Question A:</label> <input type="text" id="question_a" name="question_a" class="required">
        <label>Question B:</label> <input type="text" id="question_b" name="question_b">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset title="Thread 2">
        <legend>description two</legend>
        <label>Question C:</label> <input type="text" id="question_c" name="question_c" class="required">
        <label>Question D:</label>
        <input id="answer_d1" type="radio" name="question_d" class="required"> Answer D1
        <input id="answer_d2" type="radio" name="question_d" class="required"> Answer D2
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset title="Thread 3">
        <legend>description three</legend>
        <label>Question E:</label> <input type="text" id="question_e" name="question_e" class="required">
        <label>Question F:</label>
        <input id="answer_f1" type="radio" name="question_f" class="required"> Answer F1
        <input id="answer_f2" type="radio" name="question_f" class="required"> Answer F2
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset title="Thread 4">
        <legend>description four</legend>
        <label>Question G:</label> <input type="text" id="question_g" name="question_g" class="required">
        <label>Question H:</label> <input type="text" id="question_h" name="question_h" class="required">
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" class="finish" value="Finish!">
    </form><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

stepy.js

```
;(function($) {

    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            return this.each(function() {

                var opt     = $.extend({}, $.fn.stepy.defaults, options),
                    $this   = $(this).data('options', opt),
                    id      = $this.attr('id');

                if (id === undefined) {
                    id = 'stepy-' + $this.index();
                    $this.attr('id', id); 
                }

                var $titlesWrapper = $('<ul/>', { id: id + '-titles', 'class': 'stepy-titles' });

                if (opt.titleTarget) {
                    $(opt.titleTarget).html($titlesWrapper);
                } else {
                    $titlesWrapper.insertBefore($this);
                }

                if (opt.validate) {
                    $this.append('<div class="stepy-error"/>');
                }

                var $steps      = $this.children('fieldset'),
                    $step       = undefined,
                    $legend     = undefined,
                    description = '',
                    title       = '';

                $steps.each(function(index) {
                    $step = $(this);

                    $step
                    .addClass('step')
                    .attr('id', id + '-step-' + index)
                    .append('<p id="' + id + '-buttons-' + index + '" class="' + id + '-buttons"/>');

                    $legend = $step.children('legend');

                    if (!opt.legend) {
                        $legend.hide();
                    }

                    description = '';

                    if (opt.description) {
                        if ($legend.length) {
                            description = '<span>' + $legend.html() + '</span>';
                        } else {
                            $.error(id + ': the legend element of the step ' + (index + 1) + ' is required to set the description!');
                        }
                    }

                    title = $step.attr('title');
                    title = (title != '') ? '<div>' + title + '</div>': '--';

                    $titlesWrapper.append('<li id="' + id + '-title-' + index + '">' + title + description + '</li>');

                    if (index == 0) {
                        if ($steps.length > 1) {
                            methods.createNextButton.call($this, index);
                        }
                    } else {
                        methods.createBackButton.call($this, index);

                        $step.hide();

                        if (index < $steps.length - 1) {
                            methods.createNextButton.call($this, index);
                        }
                    }
                });

                var $titles = $titlesWrapper.children();

                $titles.first().addClass('current-step');

                var $finish = $this.children('.finish');

                if (opt.finishButton) {
                    if ($finish.length) {
                        var isForm      = $this.is('form'),
                            onSubmit    = undefined;

                        if (opt.finish && isForm) {
                            onSubmit = $this.attr('onsubmit');
                            $this.attr('onsubmit', 'return false;');
                        }

                        $finish.click(function(evt) {
                            if (opt.finish && !methods.execute.call($this, opt.finish, $steps.length - 1)) {
                                evt.preventDefault();
                            } else {
                                if (isForm) {
                                    if (onSubmit) {
                                        $this.attr('onsubmit', onSubmit);
                                    } else {
                                        $this.removeAttr('onsubmit');
                                    }

                                    var isSubmit = $finish.attr('type') == 'submit';

                                    if (!isSubmit && (!opt.validate || methods.validate.call($this, $steps.length - 1))) {
                                        $this.submit();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        $finish.appendTo($this.find('p:last'));
                    } else {
                        $.error(id + ': element with class name "finish" missing!');
                    }
                }

                if (opt.titleClick) {
                    $titles.click(function() {
                        var array   = $titles.filter('.current-step').attr('id').split('-'), // TODO: try keep the number in an attribute.
                            current = parseInt(array[array.length - 1], 10),
                            clicked = $(this).index();

                        if (clicked > current) {
                            if (opt.next && !methods.execute.call($this, opt.next, clicked)) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        } else if (clicked < current) {
                            if (opt.back && !methods.execute.call($this, opt.back, clicked)) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        if (clicked != current) {
                            methods.step.call($this, (clicked) + 1);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $titles.css('cursor', 'default');
                }

                $steps.delegate('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]', 'keypress', function(evt) {
                    var key = (evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : evt.which);

                    if (key == 13) {
                        evt.preventDefault();

                        var $buttons = $(this).parent().children('.' + id + '-buttons');

                        if ($buttons.length) {
                            var $next = $buttons.children('.button right-aligned');

                            if ($next.length) {
                                $next.click();
                            } else {
                                var $finish = $buttons.children('.finish');

                                if ($finish.length) {
                                    $finish.click();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                $steps.first().find(':input:visible:enabled').first().select().focus();
            });
        }, createBackButton: function(index) {
            var $this   = this,
                id      = this.attr('id'),
                opt     = this.data('options');

            $('<a/>', { id: id + '-back-' + index, href: 'javascript:void(0);', 'class': 'button left-aligned', html: opt.backLabel }).click(function() {
                if (!opt.back || methods.execute.call($this, opt.back, index - 1)) {
                    methods.step.call($this, (index - 1) + 1);
                }
            }).appendTo($('#' + id + '-buttons-' + index));
        }, createNextButton: function(index) {
            var $this   = this,
                id      = this.attr('id'),
                opt     = this.data('options');

            $('<a/>', { id: id + '-next-' + index, href: 'javascript:void(0);', 'class': 'button right-aligned', html: opt.nextLabel }).click(function() {
                if (!opt.next || methods.execute.call($this, opt.next, index + 1)) {
                    methods.step.call($this, (index + 1) + 1);
                }
            }).appendTo($('#' + id + '-buttons-' + index));
        }, execute: function(callback, index) {
            var isValid = callback.call(this, index + 1);

            return isValid || isValid === undefined;
        }, step: function(index) {
            index--;

            var $steps = this.children('fieldset');

            if (index > $steps.length - 1) {
                index = $steps.length - 1;
            }

            var opt = this.data('options');
                max = index;

            if (opt.validate) {
                var isValid = true;

                for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                    isValid &= methods.validate.call(this, i);

                    if (opt.block && !isValid) {
                        max = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            $steps.hide().eq(max).show();

            var $titles = $('#' + this.attr('id') + '-titles').children();

            $titles.removeClass('current-step').eq(max).addClass('current-step');

            if (this.is('form')) {
                var $fields = undefined;

                if (max == index) {
                    $fields = $steps.eq(max).find(':input:enabled:visible');
                } else {
                    $fields = $steps.eq(max).find('.error').select().focus();
                }

                $fields.first().select().focus();
            }

            if (opt.select) {
                opt.select.call(this, max + 1);
            }

            return this;
        }, validate: function(index) {
            if (!this.is('form')) {
                return true;
            }

            var $step   = this.children('fieldset').eq(index),
                isValid = true,
                $title  = $('#' + this.attr('id') + '-titles').children().eq(index),
                opt     = this.data('options'),
                $this   = this;

            $($step.find(':input:enabled').get().reverse()).each(function() {

                var fieldIsValid = $this.validate().element($(this));

                if (fieldIsValid === undefined) {
                    fieldIsValid = true;
                }

                isValid &= fieldIsValid;

                if (isValid) {
                    if (opt.errorImage) {
                        $title.removeClass('error-image');
                    }
                } else {
                    if (opt.errorImage) {
                        $title.addClass('error-image');
                    }

                    $this.validate().focusInvalid();
                }
            });

            return isValid;
        }
    };

    $.fn.stepy = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist!');
        } 
    };

    $.fn.stepy.defaults = {
        back:           undefined,
        backLabel:      '&lt; Back',
        block:          false,
        description:    true,
        errorImage:     false,
        finish:         undefined,
        finishButton:   true,
        legend:         true,
        next:           undefined,
        nextLabel:      'Next &gt;',
        titleClick:     false,
        titleTarget:    undefined,
        validate:       false,
        select:         undefined
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Michale and graphicdivine,

It is a problem inside jQuery Validation 1.9 that for default ignore **:hidden** fields as new feature, but returns undefined. Then undefined is used along the code and break when used.
We have a lot of issue about undefined returns, and this time a tried avoid hack on jQuery Stepy and fix it [1] on jQuery Validation 1.9.

Regardless of this bug fix now we have to take away the :hidden fields of the ignore option (jQuery Validation), because the option titleClick (jQuery Stepy) validates the hidden steps either, since you can skip steps without presenting it.

You can to use previous version [2] without this bug, or use the fixed version [3], not official yet.

[1] https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/pull/263
[2] http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.js
[3] github.com/wbotelhos/jquery-validation

Comment: Thank you so much...this was driving me crazy! :)

Comment: I don't really understand why the bug you describe would affect radio buttons, but I'm glad you've found a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but by switching the order of the questions, the error remains on the second set of radios.  So it would seem that your code is fine, and it's either Stepy or Validator (or the join between them) that are at fault.

http://jsfiddle.net/yBEsM/

EDIT

It seems that the error is triggered by entering the 4th fieldset, not by leaving the 3rd.

EDIT

...and taking all the "required"s off still generates the error, so I'm guessing that Stepy is the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/4KEsg/

EDIT

...although, turning FALSE stepy's VALIDATE option also solves the problem.

EDIT

With validate turned on, a single radio button is enough to break it: http://jsfiddle.net/5n5BA/1/

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  Setting "validate: false" gets rid of the error (http://jsfiddle.net/4KEsg/2/).  I think it must be the integration, as Stepy works fine with multiple radio buttons when there is no validation.

Comment: It only breaks it if there is a step/fieldset after one with a radio button.  If the radio button is on the final step, it works fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/5n5BA/2/